# How to bind an event handler to an iframe's onload with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm having some trouble getting binding to work with JQuery.

```
<iframe id="wufooFormz7x3k1" height="281" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;border:none" src="http://foo111.com"></iframe>

<script>
jQuery('#wufooFormz7x3k1').ready(function()
{
  jQuery('#wufooFormz7x3k1').bind('onload', alert('hi1'));
  jQuery('#wufooFormz7x3k1').bind('onload', function() { alert('hi2') });
});
</script>
```

The first bind generates an alert but then throws this error, and won't trigger alert for any subsequent loads of the iframe (which is what I'm trying to detect).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined and won't be triggered for subsequent onloads.
```

The second bind doesn't trigger at all.

Ideally, what I want is to bind against the iframe's onload so I can generate an alert each and every time the iframe is reloaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the load event.

```
jQuery('#wufooFormz7x3k1').bind('load', function() { alert('hi2') });
```

The first attempt alerts because you are executing the alert and passing the return value of the alert as a function, however that return value is not a function therefore an error occurs.

Also, the following isn't needed and doesn't really do what you think it does.

```
jQuery('#wufooFormz7x3k1').ready(function()
```

That ignores the `'#wufooFormz7x3k1'` and uses `document` instead. Since the script is located directly after the iframe tag, you can omit it because the iframe will be ready.